# How can I cache network data in service worker?

Tags: caching, .net-core, service-worker, angular5, progressive-web-apps

I have created Progressive Web Application (PWA) with angular 5.0 and .net core 2.0. It works fine in offline mode. But only static data are cached for offline mode. I need to store previously requested network data in service worker cache, so that I can fetch these data through service worker cache  in offline mode.

Comment: Did you saw this https://codingthesmartway.com/angular-5-service-worker/

Answer (score 2):

You can use also angular service worker for it.

> Data Groups - Cache External API Data
>   The data groups config allows you to cache external API calls, which makes it possible for your app to use an external data source without a network connection. This data is not known at build-time, so it can only be cached at runtime. There are two possible strategies for caching data sources - freshness and performance.
>
> api-freshness - This freshness strategy will attempt to serve data from the network first, then fallback to th cache. You can set a maxAge property that defines how long to cache responses and a timeout that defines how long to wait before falling back to the cache.
>
> api-performance - The performance cache will serve data from the cache first and only reach out to the network if the cache is expired.

Example you could find [here](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/hnpwa-angular-5-progressive-web-app-service-worker-tutorial/) in section *ngsw-config.json*.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check [HTTP Caching](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching).

> All you need to do is ensure that each server response provides the
>   correct HTTP header directives to instruct the browser on when and for
>   how long the browser can cache the response.

For further info, you can check the whole documentation. It provides example and illustrations to understand better about HTTP Caching.